# Why isn't Zemax showing a tilt on the wavefront on my telescope design?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, telescopes

Attached is a Zemax file [Zemax File](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=10CDA58407A779C1!45772&authkey=!ADjDQ-FjlS1JmWo&ithint=folder%2C) for an afocal telescope system. When i tilt the field by an angle of 2 degrees (In green)  I would expect a wavefront tilt at the "Image " plane, however when I look at the wave front its nearly completely flat (small peak to valley error- little bit of defocus in the system). On the diagram below you can clearly see the tilt on the image plane but why isnt this showing up in zemax. How is zemax referencing the wavefront?

[image]

I have checked the afocal system box (Ensures all wavefronts are relative to a nice flat wave) but still no tilt is seen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Zemax handles interferometry very well. You must define a Reference beam and a Test beam. It sounds like your reference and test beams are one in the same and therefore, Zemax would not register any tilt between them. I think you can designate your on-axis field as the reference and your field as the test beam. Or, you can set it up in 2 configurations and beat them together like that. It should work properly. Check your test and reference paths.

Answer (score 1):

I assume  you are not doing interferometry, but just looking at the imaging quality.  The wavefront is referenced to the chief ray, which is the ray that goes through the center of the aperture stop.  Since the chief ray is tilted at the image plane, your imaging wavefront is not tilted with respect to that ray.
       (The imaging wavefront is not tilted in your case, in the more general case, if there are more aberrations it might be tilted with respect to the chief ray).